# Check if a variable is of function type

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have any variable, which is defined as follows:

```
var a = function() {/* Statements */};
```

I want a function which checks if the type of the variable is function-like. i.e. :

```
function foo(v) {if (v is function type?) {/* do something */}};
foo(a);
```

How can I check if the variable `a` is of type `Function` in the way defined above?

Comment: here a benchmark for this most common ways to check this http://jsben.ch/#/e5Ogr

Comment: An [introspection method](https://github.com/petsel/es-function-introspection/tree/develop#readme) like [`isES3Function`](https://github.com/petsel/es-function-introspection/blob/develop/src/feature/isFunction.js#L235) detects whether the passed `value` is the function type exclusively known back at ES3, whereas [`isGenericFunction`](https://github.com/petsel/es-function-introspection/blob/develop/src/feature/isFunction.js#L261) would detect whether the passed `value` is a generic (or unspecific/non-specific) function, hence either a good old ES3 function or a non async arrow function

Comment: Nowadays function specific introspection is much more complex than what one might think first place. A few cases can be solved directly. The ones not being detectable have to be looked up from configs. The majority can be deduced by combining both approaches, applying including and excluding strategies. Detecting a good old ES3 function e.g. reads like that ... is a function type and has a writable prototype and is neither generator nor class.

Answer (score 447, accepted):

Sure underscore's way is more efficient, but the best way to check, when efficiency isn't an issue, is written on underscore's page linked by @Paul Rosania.

Inspired by underscore, the final isFunction function is as follows:

```
function isFunction(functionToCheck) {
 return functionToCheck && {}.toString.call(functionToCheck) === '[object Function]';
}
```

**Note**: This solution doesn't work for async functions, generators or proxied functions. Please see other answers for more up to date solutions.

Comment: There might be someone who has made more extensive research on the matter, but [have a look at the results of revision 4 of the jsperf with simple "result verification"](http://jsperf.com/alternative-isfunction-implementations/4). `isFunctionA` shows an implementation difference compared to the other methods.

Comment: With [updated performance tests](http://jsperf.com/alternative-isfunction-implementations/9) it looks like there's a huge speed difference depending on your browser. In Chrome `typeof(obj) === 'function'` appears to be the fastest by far; however, in Firefox `obj instanceof Function` is the clear winner.

Comment: Regarding the part: *typeof should only be used for checking if variables or properties are undefined.*
At http://javascript.info/tutorial/type-detection in the *A good use of typeof* section and the following one the author states, that the case is exactly the opposite

Comment: Alex, I'm curious why you say typeof should only be uset to check for undefined.  It's name suggests it's purpose is to check the type of something, not just whether it exists.  Are there technical issues or problems that can arise when using it to do type checking, or is it more of a preference?  If there are caveats it would be good to list them so others can avoid tripping over them.

Comment: Unfortunately, typeof can produce unusual results if you aren't careful. For instance, typeof [] // "object". Typeof certainly can be used to check the type, but be careful.

Comment: I'd like to understand why is it best. Does the other way miss some cases? If it does not, why is not the most performant solution the best one?

Comment: can someone please explain me the meaning of this string?
what does {}.toString does? And {}.toString.call(functionToCheck)?

Comment: I'm wondering how this answer gets so up-votes as when I test this in chrome, i get an exception: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .` even the `{}.toString` will cause an exception!

Comment: This has to be the worst answer I've ever seen as accepted with this many viewers (555k!!!). This is convoluted and unreadable. You should edit your answer so that people don't use this solution in their own code.

Comment: Please continue scrolling to find a much easier solution.

Comment: Update 9 years later: this will not work on recent versions of IOS when the function is behind a Proxy.

Comment: @S.Serpooshan You need to enclose this expression in parentheses. The code in the answer doesn’t have syntax errors. `{}` is a block if not in expression context. See [Why does `{} == null` give a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53306680/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon thanks, i edited the code. It is funny that `{}.toString` throws an exception (as i checked in chrome) but `({}).toString` or even `({}.toString)` are OK!

Comment: @S.Serpooshan Again, the code in the answer was fine. `{` _at the start of a statement_ is interpreted as a block. That’s why this code _alone_ doesn’t work in your console. In the answer, `{` is _not_ at the start of the statement; it’s in the middle of the expression, as part of the second operand to `&&`, where it cannot be interpreted as a block, but as an object literal, as was correctly intended. The post I linked should explain all this.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks for explanation. I think, it is more safe to embrace the `{}` between parenthesis `({})` to keep it ok all the time. consider when you are changing your code and you are not remember that `{}` should not be at begining of line..

Answer (score 2281):

```
if (typeof v === 'function') {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Just watch out for a few things like `typeof Object`, `typeof Date`, and `typeof String`, which all return `'function'` too.

Comment: @Dave, I'm not sure what the problem is since those are functions.

Comment: What is the difference with `if (v instanceOf Function)`?

Comment: @mquandalle No big difference, except `instanceof` won't work if you're checking a function that came from another document (an iframe, maybe). Performance varies.

Comment: unlike the accepted answer this works for async functions too. For an `asyncfunctionToCheck`, 
`getType.toString.call(functionToCheck)==='[object AsyncFunction]'` where as `typeof asyncfunctionToCheck === 'function'`

Comment: I don't understand why this is not the selected answer, as every object of type function returns this type correctly by simply using the "typeof" ability of JS...

Comment: What's the point to use "===" instead of simply "=="? Doesn't [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) always return a string?

Comment: @ebk - That's how I originally had it.  However, JavaScript type coercion can be dangerous, so `===` is a best practice.

Comment: Compatibility matrix: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: @MatthewCrumley - I know that this was years ago but it is clear that use cases exist having a need for semantic differentiation between a "function" and, for example, a "Date", which I am sure is what Dave Ward is referring to.

Comment: @Pancho `Date`, `Object`, and `String` are all functions, so the differentiation is there.

Comment: @Melab - Only if you actively know they are also functions - which on the face of it is less than obvious. I can only repeat that Dave Ward's observation has significant value for those who may otherwise be taken unawares by JS internal implementation characteristics. I will further note that "differentiation by name" is an inherently fallible approach as it requires a comprehensive knowledge of "all language names to exclude", both current and future.

Answer (score 201):

There are several ways so I will summarize them all

1. Best way is:

   ```js
   function foo(v) {if (v instanceof Function) {/* do something */} };
   ```

   Most performant (no string comparison) and elegant solution - the instanceof operator has been supported in browsers for a very long time, so don't worry - it will work in IE 6.
2. Next best way is:

   ```js
   function foo(v) {if (typeof v === "function") {/* do something */} };
   ```

   disadvantage of `typeof` is that it is susceptible to silent failure, bad, so if you have a typo (e.g. "finction") - in this case the `if` will just return false and you won't know you have an error until later in your code
3. The next best way is:

   ```js
   function isFunction(functionToCheck) {
       var getType = {};
       return functionToCheck && getType.toString.call(functionToCheck) === '[object Function]';
   }
   ```

   This has no advantage over solution #1 or #2 but is a lot less readable. An improved version of this is

   ```js
   function isFunction(x) {
       return Object.prototype.toString.call(x) == '[object Function]';
   }
   ```

   but still lot less semantic than solution #1

Comment: The first solution fails in case of a function passed to a different frame context. For example, from an iframe `top.Function !== Function`. To be sure, use the second one (any misspelling of "function" would be corrected during debug, hopefully).

Comment: Regarding your point about typos: any code which has this typo is likely to fail quickly/ is no more apparent than any other bugs based on typos. typeof === "function" is the cleanest solution.

Additionally your “best” solution where you use `instanceof` does not take into account multiple globals, such as a check across frames, and can return false negatives.

Comment: The typo story was just to mention the harmfulness of magic strings. Avoid magic strings where you can.

Answer (score 145):

[Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) uses a more elaborate but highly performant test:

```
_.isFunction = function(obj) {
  return !!(obj && obj.constructor && obj.call && obj.apply);
};
```

See: https://jsben.ch/B6h73

EDIT: updated tests suggest that typeof might be faster, see https://jsben.ch/B6h73

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use this approach than `typof`?

Comment: Underscore's version is *much* faster in most browsers. See: http://jsperf.com/alternative-isfunction-implementations

Comment: I sure do like underscore, simple but powerful. That said, its probably worth noting that this implementation could be spoofed by an object with those attributes.

Comment: @PaulRosania Stumbled upon these performance tests earlier today, and [updated them with verification plus more test data as revision 4](http://jsperf.com/alternative-isfunction-implementations/4) - please run it to increase browser test coverage. It's slower in operations per second (due to the many tests), but it also shows one implementation difference (open your javascript console and reload page, there might be logged error messages). Note: Revision 3 added isFunctionD (based on only `typeof == "function"`) - and it seems to be **much faster** than Underscore's "fast" version.

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading now, as Underscore.js is now on [revision 12](http://jsperf.com/alternative-isfunction-implementations/12), not the above-referenced revision 4, of its test of alternative `isFunction()` implementations. It currently uses something very close to what [dandean](http://stackoverflow.com/users/374773/dandean) suggested.

Comment: This test is wrong; consider: given `var f = function(x) { return x + 1; }; Object.setPrototypeOf(f, Object.prototype);`, `f` is still a function (`f(2)` returns `3`), but `f.call` and `f. apply` are both `undefined`.

Comment: Underscore.js now uses `typeof obj == 'function' || false`. ([Source](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/943977e34e2279503528a71ddcc2dd5f96483945/modules/isFunction.js#L11))

Answer (score 93):

**jQuery** (deprecated since version 3.3) [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isfunction/)

```
$.isFunction(functionName);
```

**AngularJS** [Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isFunction)

```
angular.isFunction(value);
```

**Lodash** [Reference](https://lodash.com/docs#isFunction)

```
_.isFunction(value);
```

**Underscore** [Reference](http://underscorejs.org/#isFunction)

```
_.isFunction(object);
```

**Node.js** deprecated since v4.0.0 [Reference](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_isfunction_object)

```
var util = require('util');
util.isFunction(object);
```

Answer (score 62):

@grandecomplex: There's a fair amount of verbosity to your solution. It would be much clearer if written like this:

```
function isFunction(x) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(x) == '[object Function]';
}
```

Comment: Object.prototype.toString.call is useful for other javascript types your interested in. You can even check against null or undefined which makes it very powerful.

Comment: This answer needs more upvotes as it is currently the most accurate

Comment: This doesn't work for async functions nor generator functions

Comment: @lwdthe1 Excellent point: `var f = async () => 5; Object.prototype.toString.call(f)` gives
`'[object AsyncFunction]'` Not insane or out of left field, but good to keep in mind.

Answer (score 58):

Something with more browser support and also include async functions could be:

```
const isFunction = value => value ? (Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === "[object Function]" || "function" === typeof value || value instanceof Function) : false;
```

and then test it like:

```
isFunction(isFunction); //true
isFunction(function(){}); //true
isFunction(()=> {}); //true
isFunction(()=> {return 1}); //true
isFunction(async function asyncFunction(){}); //true
isFunction(Array); //true
isFunction(Date); //true
isFunction(Object); //true
isFunction(Number); //true
isFunction(String); //true
isFunction(Symbol); //true
isFunction({}); //false
isFunction([]); //false
isFunction("function"); //false
isFunction(true); //false
isFunction(1); //false
isFunction("Alireza Dezfoolian"); //false
```

Comment: isFunction(null) or isFunction(undefined) returns null instead of true or false.

Comment: Also isFunction('[object Function]') gives a false positive

Answer (score 52):

```js
const foo = function() {};
if (typeof foo === 'function') {
  console.log('is function')
}
```

Comment: ...and `(() => (typeof obj === 'function') && doSomething())` is still fastest option.

Answer (score 43):

Try the `instanceof` operator: it seems that all functions inherit from the `Function` class:

```
// Test data
var f1 = function () { alert("test"); }
var o1 = { Name: "Object_1" };
F_est = function () { };
var o2 = new F_est();

// Results
alert(f1 instanceof Function); // true
alert(o1 instanceof Function); // false
alert(o2 instanceof Function); // false
```

Comment: As is pointed out elsewhere, this can fail if the function comes from another document (e.g. iframe), as each will have its own separate `Function`.

Answer (score 13):

An other simply way:

```
var fn = function () {}
if (fn.constructor === Function) {
  // true
} else {
  // false
}
```

Comment: if fn will be undefined it will throw an Error

Comment: ```fn && fn.constructor === Function``` how about this?

Answer (score 12):

For those who's interested in functional style, or looks for more expressive approach to utilize in meta programming (such as type checking), it could be interesting to see [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com) library to accomplish such task.

Next code contains only pure and pointfree functions:

```
const R = require('ramda');

const isPrototypeEquals = R.pipe(Object.getPrototypeOf, R.equals);

const equalsSyncFunction = isPrototypeEquals(() => {});

const isSyncFunction = R.pipe(Object.getPrototypeOf, equalsSyncFunction);
```

As of ES2017, `async` functions are available, so we can check against them as well:

```
const equalsAsyncFunction = isPrototypeEquals(async () => {});

const isAsyncFunction = R.pipe(Object.getPrototypeOf, equalsAsyncFunction);
```

And then combine them together:

```
const isFunction = R.either(isSyncFunction, isAsyncFunction);
```

Of course, function should be protected against `null` and `undefined` values, so to make it "safe":

```
const safeIsFunction = R.unless(R.isNil, isFunction);
```

And, complete snippet to sum up:

```
const R = require('ramda');

const isPrototypeEquals = R.pipe(Object.getPrototypeOf, R.equals);

const equalsSyncFunction = isPrototypeEquals(() => {});
const equalsAsyncFunction = isPrototypeEquals(async () => {});

const isSyncFunction = R.pipe(Object.getPrototypeOf, equalsSyncFunction);
const isAsyncFunction = R.pipe(Object.getPrototypeOf, equalsAsyncFunction);

const isFunction = R.either(isSyncFunction, isAsyncFunction);

const safeIsFunction = R.unless(R.isNil, isFunction);

// ---

console.log(safeIsFunction( function () {} ));
console.log(safeIsFunction( () => {} ));
console.log(safeIsFunction( (async () => {}) ));
console.log(safeIsFunction( new class {} ));
console.log(safeIsFunction( {} ));
console.log(safeIsFunction( [] ));
console.log(safeIsFunction( 'a' ));
console.log(safeIsFunction( 1 ));
console.log(safeIsFunction( null ));
console.log(safeIsFunction( undefined ));
```

However, note the this solution could show less performance than other available options due to extensive usage of higher-order functions.

Answer (score 7):

If you use Lodash you can do it with [_.isFunction](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isFunction).

```
_.isFunction(function(){});
// => true

_.isFunction(/abc/);
// => false

_.isFunction(true);
// => false

_.isFunction(null);
// => false
```

This method returns `true` if value is a function, else `false`.

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question but there are some considerations in 2022:

First, [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof#browser_compatibility): `instanceof` is supported by all modern browsers as well as Deno and NodeJS.
Also, it's syntactically readable and more friendly than `typeof`.
Finally, it provides a good performance over string comparison but is slower than `typeof`. Therefore, for me this is the a good option

```js
const fnc = () => {}
const isFunction = f => !!f && f instanceof Function
const isFunctionFaster = f => !!f && 'function' === typeof f

console.log({
  isFunction: isFunction(fnc),
  isFunctionFaster: isFunctionFaster(fnc),
})
```

### Notice

It is important to understand that this is a optimized function for benchmarking. When you bench mark you want to pass all the test like `null`, `undefined` and some on possible parameters received. `f && ...` filter this `null` like parameters to reduce computation time.

- Caveats of [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

This operator tests the presence of `constructor.prototype` in the object's prototype chain. This usually (though not always) means object was constructed with constructor. Therefore, this process is slower compared with `typeof` operator.

typeof v === 'function')

- Caveats of [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

This operator returns a string indicating the type of the operand's value. This is executed very fast.

- Caveats of `instanceof` and `typeof` operators:

Remember that a [class declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class), it's also considered as a function by the these operators, as you can see in this snippet:

```js
// Class Declaration
class A {}

// Instances
const obj = {}
const arr = []
const fnc = () => {}
const a = new A()

console.log('typeof')
console.log(`Object[${typeof Object}], obj[${typeof obj}]`)
console.log(`Array[${typeof Array}], arr[${typeof arr}]`)
console.log(`Function[${typeof Function}], fnc[${typeof fnc}]`)
console.log(`A[${typeof A}], a[${typeof a}]`)

console.log('instanceof')
console.log(`Object[${Object instanceof Object}], obj[${obj instanceof Object}]`)
console.log(`Array[${Array instanceof Array}], arr[${arr instanceof Array}]`)
console.log(`Function[${Function instanceof Function}], fnc[${fnc instanceof Function}]`)
console.log(`A[${A instanceof A}], a[${a instanceof A}]`)
```

Here is a basic sample of the `isFunction` and `isFunctionFaster` usage with different instances:

```js
// Functions
const isNil = o => o == null
const isFunction = f => !!f && f instanceof Function
const isFunctionFaster = f => !!f && 'function' === typeof f

class A {}

function basicFnc(){}
async function asyncFnc(){}

const arrowFnc = ()=> {}
const arrowRFnc = ()=> 1

// Not functions
const obj = {}
const arr = []
const str = 'function'
const bol = true
const num = 1
const a = new A()

const list = [
    isFunction,
    isFunctionFaster,
    basicFnc,
    arrowFnc,
    arrowRFnc,
    asyncFnc,
    Array,
    Date,
    Object,
    Number,
    String,
    Symbol,
    A,
    obj,
    arr,
    str,
    bol,
    num,
    a,
    null,
    undefined,
]

for (const arg of list) {
  console.log(`${arg} is a function: ${isFunction(arg)}`)
}
```

Here is a basic benchmark of these functions:

```js
/**
 * Figure out how long it takes for a method to execute.
 * 
 * @param {Function} method to test 
 * @param {number} iterations number of executions.
 * @param {Array} args to pass in. 
 * @param {T} context the context to call the method in.
 * @return {number} the time it took, in milliseconds to execute.
 */
const bench = (method, list, iterations, context) => {
    let start = 0
    const timer = action => {
        const time = performance.now()
        switch (action) {
            case 'start':
                start = time
                return 0
            case 'stop':
                const elapsed = time - start
                start = 0
                return elapsed
            default:
                return time - start
        }
    };

    const result = []
    timer('start')
    list = [...list]
    for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
      for (const args of list) {
        result.push(method.apply(context, args))
      }
    }
    const elapsed = timer('stop')
    
    console.log(`Called method [${method.name}]`)
    console.log(`Mean: ${elapsed / iterations}`)
    console.log(`Exec. time: ${elapsed}`)

    return elapsed
}

const fnc = () => {}
const isFunction = (f) => f && f instanceof Function
const isFunctionFaster = (f) => f && 'function' === typeof f


class A {}

function basicFnc(){}
async function asyncFnc(){}

const arrowFnc = ()=> {}
const arrowRFnc = ()=> 1

// Not functions
const obj = {}
const arr = []
const str = 'function'
const bol = true
const num = 1
const a = new A()

const list = [
    [isFunction],
    [basicFnc],
    [arrowFnc],
    [arrowRFnc],
    [asyncFnc],
    [Array],
    [Date],
    [Object],
    [Number],
    [String],
    [Symbol],
    [A],
    [obj],
    [arr],
    [str],
    [bol],
    [num],
    [a],
    [null],
    [undefined],
]

const e1 = bench(isFunction, list, 10000)
const e2 = bench(isFunctionFaster, list, 10000)

const rate = e2/e1
const percent = Math.abs(1 - rate)*100

console.log(`[isFunctionFaster] is ${(percent).toFixed(2)}% ${rate < 1 ? 'faster' : 'slower'} than [isFunction]`)
```

### Conclusion

In general `isFunctionFaster` is faster than `isFunction` in 30%.

Answer (score 5):

The below seems to work for me as well (tested from `node.js`):

```
var isFunction = function(o) {
     return Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf(o);
};

console.log(isFunction(function(){})); // true
console.log(isFunction({})); // false
```

Answer (score 4):

I found that when testing native browser functions in IE8, using `toString`, `instanceof`, and `typeof` did not work. Here is a method that works fine in IE8 (as far as I know):

```
function isFn(f){
    return !!(f && f.call && f.apply);
}
//Returns true in IE7/8
isFn(document.getElementById);
```

Alternatively, you can check for native functions using:

```
"getElementById" in document
```

Though, I have read somewhere that this will not always work in IE7 and below.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can just define a flag on the Function prototype and check if the instance you want to test inherited that

**define a flag:**

```
Function.prototype.isFunction = true;
```

**and then check if it exist**

```
var foo = function(){};
foo.isFunction; // will return true
```

The downside is that another prototype can define the same flag and then it's worthless, but if you have full control over the included modules it is the easiest way

Comment: It will fail with Error if foo is undefined. Not mentioning that you modify native prototype which is totally wrong.

Answer (score 3):

you should use **`typeOf` operator** in js.

```
var a=function(){
    alert("fun a");
}
alert(typeof a);// alerts "function"
```

Answer (score 3):

Since node v0.11 you can use the standard util function :

```
var util = require('util');
util.isFunction('foo');
```

Comment: util.isFunction is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

if you are looking for a simple solution:

```
 function isFunction(value) {
   return value instanceof Function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Becareful about this :

```
typeof Object === "function" // true.
typeof Array  === "function" // true
```

Comment: `Object` and `Array` are both constructors, even though they share some static methods you might wanna use, it's highly unlikely anybody's going to check their types like that. Are there any reasons that could happen? I currently can't come out with any except for programmer's error.

Answer (score 0):

There are functions whose arguments can be passed either as a value or though a callback. To implement them a nice helper function that utilizes type detection is the following:

```js
const toCallback = (v)=>(v instanceof Function)?v:()=>v
```

Then let's say you want to implement a function that can receive either a fixed value or a callback that returns the value. See below:

```js
let someFunction=(valueOrFunction)=>{
    let f = toCallback(valueOrFunction); 
    [1,2,3].forEach(v=>console.log(`value passed: ${f()}`))   
}
```

and now you can execute the above in two ways:

```js
someFunction(5);
//value passed: 5
//value passed: 5
//value passed: 5

someFunction(()=>Math.random());
//value passed: 0.3218832537523002
//value passed: 0.2343617971814611
//value passed: 0.38216627030533656
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky question as you need to define "what is a function?" first.
Let's look at node (V8 implementation of JavaScript engine). It is written in C++ but also has parts in JavaScript.
Some functions are magically mapped to **C++ functions**. Those do not have all the properties of standard function.
Other functions are simply **JavaScript functions with prototype set to null**. It means they don't inherit from Object and wouldn't have methods such as toString() and similar.
Then finally you have **standard instances of Function**.
And there is also **AsyncFunction** which is a Function but a bit different.
Think what about a promise that returns a function - is it a Function or rather a Promise? Is Promise a Function?

This told let's see how node implements checking if an argument is an AsyncFunction:
[readable-stream](https://github.com/nodejs/readable-stream/blob/268229d67620d092ea4d64de5416f55997eadbaa/src/util.js#L5C55-L5C55) defined AsyncFunction as a prototype of async function.
Then type check is simply `typeof arg === 'function'` as seen [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/41e225cac41ae7c1d25c400c45bb58e5d07b4657/lib/util.js#L176).

- You need to define "what is a function" first
- If you understand it as an instance of some class then you can use for example `arg instanceof Function` which returns a boolean
- If you wish to see what the function inherits from then you could check its prototype
- If you define anything that can be called a function - check if it is callable
- There are still some issues with that :(

```
// It doesn't really matter if you use named function or not - but that is cool to know that it can have a name :)
let f = function aNamedFunction(){console.log('hello')};
f.prototype = null;
console.log(f instanceof Function, typeof f); // true, function
f.__proto__ = null;
console.log(f instanceof Function); // false, function
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(f)); // prototype, length, name
f(); // 'hello'
```

To summarize:
The `typeof arg === 'function'` seems pretty good (though there are few fancy scenarios where it would fail).

Comment: [Function specific introspection](https://github.com/petsel/es-function-introspection/tree/develop#readme) is even more complex than what you mentioned above. Few cases can be solved directly. The ones not being detectable have to be looked up from configs. The majority can be deduced by combining both approaches, applying including/excluding strategies. [Detecting a good old ES3 function](https://github.com/petsel/es-function-introspection/blob/develop/src/feature/isFunction.js#L235) e.g. reads like that ... is a function type and has a writable prototype and is neither generator nor class.