# typeof new Function() always "function"?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, cross-browser, typeof

`typeof new Number(1)` will return `"object"`, same with instantiated strings, etc.

Is it safe to use `typeof myVar === "function"` or are there any browsers that will return `"object"` when using the `Function` constructor (don't know why they should do, but maybe there is any one)?

Comment: if you want to detect function objects, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999998/how-can-i-check-if-a-javascript-variable-is-function-type

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
if (myVar instanceof Function)
```

instead. However, myVar instanceof Object would also be true, since it's a derived type. I'm not sure if this is "more" cross-browser compatible, but I'm fairly certain that it's part of ecma-standard.

Answer (score 0):

I use it in all my applications and  I never had problems.
It's safe to use .

[ECMAScript Definition](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.4.3)