# Node js check if a var is a function

Tags: node.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check if a javascript variable is function type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999998/how-can-i-check-if-a-javascript-variable-is-function-type)

How i check if a variable is a function
for Array exist `Array.isArray()`
but `Function.isFunction` dos'nt exist

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5999998/

Comment: Worth mentioning that the accepted/best answer here is simpler than the referenced question, as this is just for node ( no compatibility issues )

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
if (typeof variable === 'function') {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: `typeof class A {} === "function"` is `true`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `instanceof` operator.

```
var fn = function() {};
var result = fn instanceof Function; // result will be true
```

It also respects prototypal inheritance.

Answer (score 4):

Underscore.js is a library that has a lot of useful helpers, like the one you're looking for.

http://underscorejs.org/

```
_ = require('underscore');

var aFunction = function() { };
var notFunction = 'Not a function';

_.isFunction(aFunction); // true
_.isFunction(notFunction); // false
```

Comment: I wouldn't use underscore for this case, given that the _.isFunction function is just `typeof obj == 'function' || false` - https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/e944e0275abb3e1f366417ba8facb5754a7ad273/underscore.js#L1338

Answer (score 1):

```
var fn = function() {},
    toString = Object.prototype.toString;

first way:

if( toString.call( function(){} ) === '[object Function]' ) {
    //if is Function do something...
}

second way:

if( fn.constructor.name = 'Function' ) {
    //if is Function do something...
}
```

Hope it helps cheers:)!