# Checking if a function is of type Function in javascript

Tags: javascript, apply

Yes, I know there are plenty of posts on this, but I do not understand  the selected answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999998/how-can-i-check-if-a-javascript-variable-is-function-type). Particularly, why is it necessary to `return object`?

Why wouldn't something like `Object.prototype.toString.call(myFunc)` be sufficient as described by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)?

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin: That isn't actually necessary, though; they both work fine.

Comment: The point of duck-typing should be that you don't care if it's a `Function`, only whether it implements `apply` and `call`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is it necessary to `return object`?

It's not necessary to do `object &&`, but a shortcut for falsy values that avoids the method call for values such as `null`. Of course, if you're looking for speed, you probably should go for `typeof object == "function"`

> Why wouldn't something like `Object.prototype.toString.call(myFunc)` be sufficient?

It is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
return object && getClass.call(object) == '[object Function]'
```

This construction simply verifies if `object` is not `null` or `undefined` (generally falsy).
This way it's faster, because JavaScript doesn't evaluate the `getClass()` call on a falsy `object`.