# JQuery verify if a var is a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How i verify if my callBackFunction is defined as a function with jquery?

```
var callBackFunction =window['columnActive'];
(...)
            "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                if ($.isFunction(callBackFunction)) {
                    alert('cheguei');
                    columnActive(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull);
                }

        }
```

Comment: It fails on the test

Comment: Ignore the top answer in the duplicate, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6000009/519413) is the correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this, the built-in (and globally supported) [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) will tell you:

`if (typeof callBackFunction === 'function')`

`typeof` also works even if `callBackFunction` was never defined or declared, while jQuery and others will throw an error if you call `$.isFunction(x)` and `x` was never declared.

Comment: still fail on the test

Comment: Then maybe `callBackFunction` *isn't* a function...

Comment: to declare a var is a function is this way:var callBackFunction = window['columnActive']; correct?

Comment: I think the problem is how I declare the var callBackFunction

Comment: I figure out, its because is in document ready