# How to test javascript Promise function in jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

```
this.result = new Promise( function( resolve, reject ){
   self.resolveMethod = resolve;
   self.rejectMethod = reject;
});
```

How can I test resolveMethod and rejectMethod are functions? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a javascript variable is function type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999998/how-can-i-check-if-a-javascript-variable-is-function-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me

```
describe('result', function() {
    it('should assign resolve function to resolveMethod', function() {
        expect( instance.resolveMethod ).toEqual( jasmine.any(Function) );
    });
    it('should assign reject function to rejectMethod', function() {
        expect( instance.rejectMethod ).toEqual( jasmine.any(Function) );
    });       
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this helper method and assert.

```
function isFunctionA(object) {
 return object && getClass.call(object) == '[object Function]';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
expect(type(result.resolveMethod).toBe('function');
expect(type(result.rejectMethod).toBe('function');
```