# How to check if a component prop is a function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass a function to a component as a prop and use it in its render function, I seem to be missing a key concept here.

For example

**index.jsx**

```
render(<MyComponent d={data} showName = {d => d.name + ' ' + d.surname}/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**MyComponent.jsx**

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <h1>if (typeof this.props.showName === 'function') {
            //call this.props.showName(d)
        }
    }
}
```

**edit**

I want the showName prop to be either a function or a value and the component doesn't need to know about it beforehand.

**edit2**

On second thought, I think I'll build a component so it can use both a function and a value as a prop, but keep them separate so that I can validate them better. E.g. I'll either use

```
<MyComponent value="some value"/>
```

or

```
<MyComponent calculatedValue = {// a function}/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

You can do it like this and if it's not a function it will tell you:

```
     MyComponent.propTypes = {
           showName: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
     };
```

This is the react way to do it ;)

Edit: I got it now, you can do an assertion on the prop by calling it with an argument, if the assertion fails, you'll know it's not a function. Check this package on npm, it's easy to use it out of the box

https://www.npmjs.com/package/assert

Comment: Thanks. What if my component does not know in advance what the function will be called (or whether a prop will in fact be a function or not)? I'm trying to build a component which is flexible in that way, I'll edit my question.

Comment: Check my edit for, assertion is the key for a more advanced use

Comment: I think I'll use this approach and modify my logic a bit. I'll either use a value or a function and just name the props differently (e.g. val, valFunc) and check which is passed.
Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Write it like this:

```
checkMethod(){
    if(typeof(this.props.showName) === 'function') {
        //call this.props.showName(d);
        return null;
    }else{
        return this.props.showName;
    }    
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return 
            <h1>
                {this.checkMethod()}
            </h1>
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <h1>if (typeof this.props.showName === 'function') {
            //call this.props.showName(d)
        }
    }
}
```

Your above code seems fine. But your approach is wrong.

You need to validate props using propTypes

```
MyComponent .propTypes = {
showName : React.PropTypes.func
};
```

Here is the other checks,

```
propArray: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
   propBool: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
   propFunc: React.PropTypes.func,
   propNumber: React.PropTypes.number,
   propString: React.PropTypes.string,
   propObject: React.PropTypes.object
```

---

> React.PropTypes has moved into a different package since React v15.5. Please use the prop-types library instead.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
    );
  }
}

Greeting.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use propTypes for whatever reason , you could use this, this is simple JavaScript :

```
function isFunction(functionToCheck) {
 var getType = {};
 return functionToCheck && getType.toString.call(functionToCheck) === '[object Function]';
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999998/how-can-i-check-if-a-javascript-variable-is-function-type)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried React.PropTypes.func ?

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: I would steer away from answer with "Have you tried" or "Try" because it becomes more of a comment than a specific answer (it leaves some uncertainty about your response)

Answer (score 0):

My component needs to check if `this.props.update` is a function. Not sure if it's a right solution, but it definitely works in my case:

```
if ("update" in this.props) {
     this.props.update(data);
}
```