# Finding original values JS

Tags: javascript

How do I create a function that would receive one argument and would print in the console the underlying value of that argument, whether it be a primitive type or a function?

```
value = function(args){ 
    return args.valueOf() //Only working for line 36
};

var scary = 'boo';
var first = function() { return 'bar'; };
var second = function() {
    return first;
};

var third = function() {
    return second;
};

var nested = function() {
  return function() {
    return function() {
      return function() {
        return function() {
          return function() {
            return function() {
              return function() {
                return function() {
                  return 'super nested';
                };
              };
            };
          };
        };
      };
    };
  };
};


// expected values for all these assessments
console.log(value(scary));   // should be      'boo'
console.log(value(first));   // should be      'bar'
console.log(value(second));  // should also be 'bar'
console.log(value(third));   // should also be 'bar'
console.log(value(nested));  // should be      'super nested'
```

The value function I made here only gives me the first line for scary and just the functions for the rest, how do I get the values of the other functions?

Comment: Not everybody likes to navigate to external sources for code (+ it's very likely that this link will expire at some time in the future) so you might as well make your code part of the question itself

Comment: @Icepickle Done :)

Answer (score 5):

You can check if the `args` you received has [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), and if so, reuse your `value` function with the result of your argument

If not, you return the value

```js
var value = function(args){ 
    if (args && args.apply) {
      return value( args() );
    }
    return args;
};

var scary = 'boo';
var first = function() { return 'bar'; };
var second = function() {
    return first;
};

var third = function() {
    return second;
};

var nested = function() {
  return function() {
    return function() {
      return function() {
        return function() {
          return function() {
            return function() {
              return function() {
                return function() {
                  return 'super nested';
                };
              };
            };
          };
        };
      };
    };
  };
};


// expected values for all these assessments
console.log(value(scary));   // should be      'boo'
console.log(value(first));   // should be      'bar'
console.log(value(second));  // should also be 'bar'
console.log(value(third));   // should also be 'bar'
console.log(value(nested));  // should be      'super nested'
```

Or you can use a similar method like the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999998/how-can-i-check-if-a-javascript-variable-is-function-type) to see if it is a function, I most often use the [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) functionality.

As Ibu mentioned in the comments, if you need such a value function, you might need to check your code design. It could be a lot more optimized :)

Comment: Works wonderfully. However, I would still ask the OP to try to rethink his design. If you have to make so many nested functions you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @Ibu I would agree :) without a doubt :)

Comment: @CarlMarkham Maybe, however it was a valid question. What is the diff with helping somebody to do the job they are paid to do, or for their homework?

Answer (score 3):

Although already answered, another solution would be to check the `typeof` args

```js
var value = function(args){ 
    if (typeof args === 'function') {
        return value(args.call());
    }
    return args.valueOf() //Only working for line 36
};

var scary = 'boo';
var first = function() { return 'bar'; };
var second = function() {
    return first;
};

var third = function() {
    return second;
};

var nested = function() {
  return function() {
    return function() {
      return function() {
        return function() {
          return function() {
            return function() {
              return function() {
                return function() {
                  return 'super nested';
                };
              };
            };
          };
        };
      };
    };
  };
};


// expected values for all these assessments
console.log(value(scary));   // should be      'boo'
console.log(value(first));   // should be      'bar'
console.log(value(second));  // should also be 'bar'
console.log(value(third));   // should also be 'bar'
console.log(value(nested));  // should be      'super nested'
```