# Determine if a Function Argument is a Function Call

Tags: r

I want to be able to determine if an argument to a function is a call to a function or not. Lets say I have two functions , `f()` and `g()`:

```
f <- function() "foo" 

g <- function(x){
  ???
}
```

I want the output to the calls as below:

```
g(f())
#> [1] TRUE
g("bar")
#> [1] FALSE
```

I can get this to work by quoting the function arguments:

```
f <- function() "foo" 

g <- function(x) is.call(x)

g(quote(f()))
#> [1] TRUE
g(quote("bar"))
#> [1] FALSE
```

However this is sub-optimal as I don't want users of the function to have to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: See this link and let us know if it was helpful: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999998/how-can-i-check-if-a-javascript-variable-is-function-type>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `substitute()`:

```
h <- function(x) is.call(substitute(x))
h(f())
# [1] TRUE
```