# Why does `{} == null` give a SyntaxError?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I can compare {} to true or false or itself, but comparison to null or undefined gives a syntax error. Is this because {} is an object value and not a reference? It feels weird that it would be a Syntax Error instead of some kind of runtime type error, or just work.

To clarify, I'm curious why this is a SyntaxError, mostly compared to doing `{} == {}` which is not only not a SyntaxError, but no error at all.

[image: Example of weird behavior]

Comment: for some reason the REPL seems to treat it as a block statement there

Comment: When you put everything in parentheses, `({} == null)`, it returns false. Firefox doesn't like comparing it at all: `{} == {}` throws a syntax error, except if you put in parentheses.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the

Comment: #3 in the dupe. {} is seen as a block statement that does not return anything so it is same as `undefined  == null`

Comment: @espascarello nope. why does `{} === {}` evaluate to *false* then?!

Comment: Why would it be true @JonasWilms? Objects comparing never equals. and that is a block statement equal to an object.

Comment: @espascarello no it is not! That would be a SyntaxError as well. But why isn't it? For some reason the REPL seems to treat some values as "in expression context" and some not.

Comment: Why would it be a syntax error.... lol, glad my dupe was removed for you can prove it with an answer. lol

Comment: @epascarello why would the last be a SyntaxError?

Comment: @epascarello yup, because it was no dupe, you just don't get the question

Comment: I've been playing with this in [Treehugger](https://ajaxorg.github.io/treehugger/test.html), an AST viewer.  Enter the expression into TreeHugger, and notice it thinks the `{}` is a block start unless its in parenthesis.

Comment: @amy now what happens if you enter `{} == {}` ?

Comment: @JonasWilms You are free to try it out yourself.  [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net/) gives similar results.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Comment: @amy I just did and `{} == {}` results in an error as the first operand is missing.

Comment: @epascarello not sure how that matters. The last line isnt even evaluated, while the second last one is

Comment: @JonasWilms Okay?  I didn't ask, but good to know.  http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html also gives similar results.  I think I'm running out of AST viewers.

Comment: @JonasWilms: Chrome uses a heuristic to evaluate code that starts with a `{` as an expression instead of a statement. It looks like that heuristic doesn't detect `{} == null`.

Comment: using if statement can not throw a SyntaxError

Comment: @felixKling thats quite naive isn't it?

Comment: @JonasWilms: Sure. No idea how it works `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` . Might just be a bug.

Comment: @felixKling bergi linked the relevant source in the dupe,  its just a regex to check for `{` and `}`, which is ... pragmatic....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two main contexts when parsing code: the expression context and the statement context. The body of a function for example is a statement context, the right side of an assignment is an expression context. To distinguish both makes sense to forbid things like:

```
 if( if(true) ) alert("nonsense");
```

Now REPL have a really difficult task: On the one hand, they have to parse functions and codeblocks that get entered, and on the other hand you sometimes just want to check how a certain object look like. Therefore this:

```
 { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

is actually a SyntaxError in JavaScript, as a `{` in a statement context starts a block of code, and `:` is invalid then. However the REPL is clever enough and puts that object into an expression context, and evaluates it as if it would be in parens:

```
({ a: 1, b: 2 })
```

the same happens for:

```
 {} == {}
```

which is actually also a SyntaxError, however the REPL also moves it into an expression context:

```
 ({} == {})
```

That "moving into an expression context" is a complicated task, and it seems as if the REPL just does not see the expression here:

```
 {} == null
```

and therefore parses `{}` as a block. Thats the case because the REPL just naively checks if the first and the last character are `{` and `}`, which is the case for `{} == {}` but not for `{} == null`.

Relevant part of the [chromium sourcecode](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/4fd348fdb9c0b3842829acdfb2b82c86dacd8e0a%5E!/#F2):

```
 if (/^\s*\{/.test(text) && /\}\s*$/.test(text))
  text = '(' + text + ')';

executionContext.evaluate(text, "console", !!useCommandLineAPI, false, false, true, printResult);
```

Comment: I'm really glad someone else was as interested in this dumb bit of REPL weirdness as I was :)

Comment: @christopher I'm really surprised that there are so many duplicates ... I never heard of this behaviour before ....

Comment: mad props for finding the relevant bit of chromium sourcecode