# Why Node REPL evaluates expressions differently depending on whether it's assigned to variable or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's consider the following input in terminal

```sh
✗ node
Welcome to Node.js v13.1.0.
Type ".help" for more information.

> let a = 13
undefined
> {} + a.toString()
13

> // but
undefined

> let b = {} + a.toString()
undefined
> b
'[object Object]13'
```

The question is why when you evaluate `{} + a.toString()` REPL will show a digit 13, but when you assign it to a variable it equals to the expected string `'[object Object]13'`?

This behaviour happens at least in the V8 (Node and Chrome).

Comment: I guess `{}` is a block statement.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53306680/why-does-null-give-a-syntaxerror/53307328?r=SearchResults#53307328)

Comment: repls/consoles are weird. For example, `{a+3}` is a block, 
 `{a:3}` isn't.

Comment: For a moment I doubted my understanding of JavaScript. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root problem here is that `{` ... `}` in JS is syntactically either a *block statement* or an *object literal expression*, depending on the context (wether a *statement* or an *expression* is expected). In your second case, it is clearly an expression:

```
 let b = /*expression context*/
```

thus `{}` is an object literal there. In the first case, it is in a *statement context*, and thus is interpreted as:

```
  {} // an empty block statement
  + a.toString() // a unary plus operator on "13"
```

Comment: Which 100% makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :)