# more than one setState in useEffect, how to aviod re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

how to avoid re-render when i have more than one setState in useEffect ?

i want to make 2 API calls and set 3 different states in useEffect ( when component did mount ) and only one re-render

something like this

```
useEffect(()=>{
   axios.get('http://localhost:81/api/myapi/')
   .then(res=>{
     setName(res.data['name']);
     setPrice(res.data['price']);
   })

   axios.get('http://localhost:81/api/mysecondapi/')
   .then(res=>{
     setColors(res.data['colors']);
   })
 },[]);
```

i want only one render after all the sets. i know it's correct to a re-render after every setStates, but how can i make this to do only one ?
is it good to put all states in an object ? like class state ?

Comment: Yes, you can put all state in an object and use useReducer instead of useState.

Comment: You can refer to - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53574614/multiple-calls-to-state-updater-from-usestate-in-component-causes-multiple-re-re . seems like same problem

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `useReducer`, could could use `Promise.all` with your fetches

```
useEffect(()=>{
   const stateData = {}
   const fetch1 = axios.get('http://localhost:81/api/myapi/')
   const fetch2 = axios.get('http://localhost:81/api/mysecondapi/')
   Promise.all([fetch1, fetch2]).then(([res1,res2])=>{
     setName(res1.data['name']);
     setPrice(res1.data['price']);
     setColors(res2.data['colors']);
   })
 },[]);
```

This will cause 3x re-renders, but that isn't the same as 3x DOM updates.

If you only want a single re-render, combine all your updates into one object:

```
Promise.all([fetch1, fetch2]).then(([res1, res2]) => {
  setNamePriceColor({ name: res1.data['name'],
    price: res1.data['price'],
    colors: res2.data['colors'] })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try chaining promises

```
useEffect(()=> {
   axios.get('http://localhost:81/api/myapi/')
   .then(res => {
     setName(res.data['name']);
     setPrice(res.data['price']);
   })
   .then(() => axios.get('http://localhost:81/api/mysecondapi/'))
   .then(res => {
     setColors(res.data['colors']);
   })

 },[]);
```

If you have to separeted `axios` call, react won't be able to [batch the state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).