# (ReactJS) Separate trigger for each Collapsible element (react-collapsible)

Tags: reactjs, use-state

How can I make a separate trigger for each Collapsible element with a single useState (preferably)?

**CodeSandBox** - https://codesandbox.io/s/separate-triggers-question-forked-vgs5b

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Collapsible from "react-collapsible";

function App() {
  const database = [
    { id: 1, name: "Name1", description: "Desc1" },
    { id: 2, name: "Name2", description: "Desc2" },
    { id: 3, name: "Name3", description: "Desc3" },
    { id: 4, name: "Name4", description: "Desc4" },
    { id: 5, name: "Name5", description: "Desc5" }
  ];

  const [items, setItems] = React.useState(database);
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="tracker_master">
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <div onClick={() => setOpen(!open)} key={item.id}>
          {item.name.toUpperCase()}

          <Collapsible open={open}>
            <div>{item.description.toUpperCase()}</div>
          </Collapsible>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Just check this, if this might resolve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53574614/multiple-calls-to-state-updater-from-usestate-in-component-causes-multiple-re-re

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have seperate triggers for each item I recommend to  abstract each element into its own component that has its own open state.

So you could do something like this:

```
const Item = ({ item }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div onClick={() => setOpen(!open)} key={item.id}>
      {item.name.toUpperCase()}

      <Collapsible open={open}>
        <div>{item.description.toUpperCase()}</div>
      </Collapsible>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const database = [
    { id: 1, name: "Name1", description: "Desc1" },
    { id: 2, name: "Name2", description: "Desc2" },
    { id: 3, name: "Name3", description: "Desc3" },
    { id: 4, name: "Name4", description: "Desc4" },
    { id: 5, name: "Name5", description: "Desc5" }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="tracker_master">
      {database.map((item) => (
        <Item item={item} key={item.id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/separate-triggers-question-forked-ryvp7?file=/src/App.js:0-850)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use single `useState` then your single state object should manage open flag of all the items as shown below (I have updated your code and tested its working fine).

`openFlags` is single state which maintains the open flag of each item by id and use it for triggering collabse and expand the items independently.

```
import React from "react";
import Collapsible from "react-collapsible";

function App() {
  const database = [
    { id: 1, name: "Name1", description: "Desc1" },
    { id: 2, name: "Name2", description: "Desc2" },
    { id: 3, name: "Name3", description: "Desc3" },
    { id: 4, name: "Name4", description: "Desc4" },
    { id: 5, name: "Name5", description: "Desc5" }
  ];

  const [items, setItems] = React.useState(database);
  let initialOpenFlags = {}
   items.forEach((i) => {
    initialOpenFlags = {
      ...initialOpenFlags,
      [i.id]: false
    };
  });
  const [openFlags, setOpenFlags] = React.useState(initialOpenFlags);

  return (
    <div className="tracker_master">
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <div
          onClick={() =>
            setOpenFlags({ ...openFlags, [item.id]: !openFlags[item.id] })
          }
          key={item.id}
        >
          {item.name.toUpperCase()}

          <Collapsible open={openFlags[item.id]}>
            <div>{item.description.toUpperCase()}</div>
          </Collapsible>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```