# useState resets with each re-render

Tags: react-native

I have a functional component and am using useState to store some values in an object. No matter what, on re-render, the object seems to be wiped and then set to the initial value. But if I store, e.g. a simple string, it behaves as expected.

```
MyCompontent = (props) => {

  const [name,setName] = useState('Bob')
  const [stateDict,setStateDict] = useState({
    number: 1, 
    color: green,
    somethingElse: undefined,
    aFourthThing: {}
  })

  console.log(`${name}, ${number}`)
  //first pass, name is Bob, number is 1
  //second pass, name changes to Fred, number is still 1

  if (name == "Bob") { setName("Fred") }
  
  if (stateDict.number == 1) { 
   setStateDict({...stateDict,  number: 2})
  }

}
```

What about the Object in state makes it behave differently? Or am I doing my update incorrectly? I followed some other SO posts on how to store objects in state.

Comment: Why do you need to access the variable above the hook call? The variable isn't defined on any call until the `useState` line, as you've seen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198849/what-is-the-temporal-dead-zone

Comment: You should get a `reference error - cannot access 'name' before initialization`

Comment: Hey @ggorlen -- I was misunderstanding what was going on. There is still something weird going on, but I updated the post to reflect the actual problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Set the state inside a `function` or `useEffect` hook, why are you doing it inside the body of the main function?

Comment: Can you share a runnable [mcve] as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support/338538#338538)? I don't see a problem with this code other than `green` being undefined, which I assume is unintentional. Maybe this is the problem? [Multiple calls to state updater from useState in component causes multiple re-renders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53574614/multiple-calls-to-state-updater-from-usestate-in-component-causes-multiple-re-re)