# My setState hook won't happen immediately

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I have multipe hook.

```js
const [A, setA] = useState([]);
const [B, setB] = useState([]);
    
useEffect(() => {
  setA(["foo"]);
  setB(["bar"]);
}, []);
    
useEffect(() => console.log(A), [A])
useEffect(() => console.log(B), [B])
```

A update is reflected immediately and B is not. If I flip the order, the result is also flipped (B is reflected immediately).

How do I make those two updates to happen together?

Edit: I use useEffect to check my state.

Answer (score 0):

On React 17 this is the default behavior, you get 1 render per state change.

Starting React 18 state changes might be batched together, but if you want to be sure they always get changed together you need 1 state variable, not two.

Comment: can you please share any link referencing to this? because what you said isn't clear to me

Comment: @MeetBhalodiya here's a reference from the blog: https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#new-feature-automatic-batching lmk if this is still confusing

Answer (score -1):

This question was already asked in Stackoverflow once.

Like @Evert mentioned, if the multiple states are closely related, then it's better to batch them together. Each state updates causes a component re-render, and as of I think it can't be changed in any way.

So group your states together so that you update the whole group itself, causing only one state update per batch state update.

```
const [aAndb, setAAndB] = useReducer(
  (state, newState) => ({...state, ...newState}),
  {A: "foo", B: "bar"}
)

setAAndB({A: "Bar"});
```

And here's the [other similar question that I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53574614/multiple-calls-to-state-updater-from-usestate-in-component-causes-multiple-re-re)