# What is the best way to check if variable is a function?

Tags: javascript, function, typeof

I have gone through multiple approaches to check if a variable is a function but I can't figure out the advantages and disadvantages, which one to use and why.

Are there any edge cases where my comparison can fail in case of `typeof`?

1) `function isFunction(functionToCheck) { 
return functionToCheck && {}.toString.call(functionToCheck) === '[object Function]'; }`

2) `typeof functionToCheck === 'function'`

3) `functionToCheck.constructor === Function`

Comment: Hi. May this link helps to you
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-a-variable-is-of-function-type-using-javascript/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a variable is of function type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999998/check-if-a-variable-is-of-function-type)

Comment: use `typeof method_to_evaluate === 'function'`

Answer (score 4):

In a perfect world, all of them should return the same value.

```js
const functionToCheck = () => {};


console.log(isFunction(functionToCheck));
console.log(typeof functionToCheck === 'function');
console.log(functionToCheck.constructor === Function);
console.log(functionToCheck instanceof Function);


function isFunction(functionToCheck){
  return functionToCheck && {}.toString.call(functionToCheck) === '[object Function]';
}
```

In real world, their difference can be significant.

```js
const functionToCheck = () => {};

// Altering `.toString()` function by some third-party code
Object.prototype.toString = function(){
  return '[ABCDEFG]';
}

// Mistake of programmer
functionToCheck.constructor = HTMLElement;

// Having a global scope variable named `Function` by some third-party code
window.Function = class ABC {};


console.log(isFunction(functionToCheck));
console.log(typeof functionToCheck === 'function');
console.log(functionToCheck.constructor === Function);
console.log(functionToCheck instanceof Function);


function isFunction(functionToCheck){
  return functionToCheck && {}.toString.call(functionToCheck) === '[object Function]';
}
```

As you can see, I can freely alter the functions and constructor which in turn alter the results that you expect.

The **safest** way is to always use `typeof` to check a function as its result cannot be altered in any way.