# Javascript execute optional function of object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I have an object like this

```
 const obj = {
     func: props.func, // we don't know if func is a function or undefined...
 }
```

and I have this in my code:

```
 obj.func(params);
```

What is the good way to execute the optional function of the object?

I have thought to do something like this:

```
if(typeof obj.func === "function")
   obj.func(params);
```

or

```
try {
    obj.func(params);
} catch (err) {}
```

But I'm not sure if both forms are correct to do it (or if there is a better way) as I don't have much experience with javascript.

Someone who knows? Thank you.

Comment: Either could be good, depends on the type of check you want to accomplish. Also, consider reading about EAFP vs LBYL and check what's preferred approach is used in your application.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999998/check-if-a-variable-is-of-function-type check this

Comment: ES2020 [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). `obj.func?.()`

Comment: will this work? obj.func?.("hello world!");

Answer (score -1):

Read about optional chaining in JS [here](https://javascript.info/optional-chaining)

Personally, I would use this way from ES2020:

```
const props = {
  func: Math.random() >= 0.5 ? undefined : (params) => console.log(params),
};

const obj = {
   func: props.func,
};
```

And then

```
obj.func?.("hello world!");
```

This way is recommended [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Encadenamiento_opcional)

Answer (score -1):

I personally would go with

```
if (typeof obj.func === "function") {
    obj.func();
}
```

because if you use a try catch, and an error occurred within the function itself, it might appear as though the function was never called in the first place.