Why not using `typeof` in JavaScript code to check if a value is a function?
I saw the following code in this Github's link:
isFunction(value) {
    return !!(value && value.constructor && value.call && value.apply);
}

And wondered why it has to be such long while we can simply use typeof value === 'function'. So, is there any difference or useful purpose of using the above code compared to the typeof check?

there's a chance it's just a strategy to achieve better performance for the task ... here there's a deep analysis on those regards https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999998/check-if-a-variable-is-of-function-type
